# Unable to plot matplotlib fig after training NN

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, matplotlib, keras

Any time I train a NN (using TensorFlow with keras) and attempt to plot (matplotlib) the loss history of the fit model, the kernel dies. I do not think it is code because running different code from different validated sources (links below) causes the same problem.

Also, it appears to be specific to TensorFlow and matplotlib. If I run a sklearn model and then plot it works fine.

Example links:

https://github.com/chrisalbon/notes/blob/master/docs/deep_learning/keras/visualize_loss_history.ipynb

https://machinelearningmastery.com/tutorial-first-neural-network-python-keras/

Tried fixes:

1. Restarting comp
2. Removing keras and matplotlib
3. Rolling back matplotlib to a previous version (3.02)
4. Updating Python 3.6 to 3.71
5. Uninstalling Python and anaconda from comp and re-installing
6. Running code in different browser (Safari and Chrome)

I believe it has something to do with my installation. I sent the notebook and data to someone else with the same exact comp and setup and it worked fine.

I've also tried running the py file through the command line to retrieve errors, but nothing happens (no error, no indication that the file is running). Other py files run though.

Current versions

- OS - Mojave v10.14.5
- Python - 3.71
- Matplotlib - 3.0.3
- Keras - 2.2.4
- TensorFlow - 1.13.1

Answer (score 0):

After trial and error the issue appears to stem from a bug in TensorFlow. I'm not sure of the full specifics to what is causing the issue, but when TensorFlow is rolled back to 1.11 the issue no longer occurs. So for anyone who is also experiencing this problem, you may want to try rolling back TensorFlow.